# Getting Jekyll build error with jekyll 3.9.0 ruby 2.7.5

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I am getting below error with ruby 2.7.5 and jekyll 3.9.0. Any work around?

```
bundle exec jekyll build

npx percy snapshot _site/ --ignore-files “assets/python/**,parallel-universe/index.html”


Configuration file: /home/circleci/repo/docs/_config.yml

Source: /home/circleci/repo/docs

Destination: /home/circleci/repo/docs/_site

Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
Generating…

jekyll 3.9.0 | Error: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)

/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/csv-3.2.3/lib/csv.rb:1791:in read': wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) (ArgumentError) from /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/readers/data_reader.rb:57:in read_data_file’
from /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/readers/data_reader.rb:46:in block in read_data_to' from /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/readers/data_reader.rb:38:in each’
from /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/readers/data_reader.rb:38:in read_data_to' from /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/readers/data_reader.rb:20:in read’
from /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/reader.rb:18:in read' from /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:164:in read’
from /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:69:in process' from /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:28:in process_site’
from /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:65:in build' from /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:36:in process’
from /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:18:in block (2 levels) in init_with_program' from /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in block in execute’
from /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in each' from /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in execute’
from /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in go' from /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in program’
from /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/exe/jekyll:15:in <top (required)>' from /home/circleci/.rubygems/bin/jekyll:25:in load’
from /home/circleci/.rubygems/bin/jekyll:25:in <top (required)>' from /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.11/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in load’
from /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.11/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in kernel_load' from /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.11/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:23:in run’
from /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.11/lib/bundler/cli.rb:483:in exec' from /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.11/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in run’
from /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.11/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in invoke_command' from /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.11/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in dispatch’
from /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.11/lib/bundler/cli.rb:31:in dispatch' from /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.11/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in start’
from /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.11/lib/bundler/cli.rb:25:in start' from /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.11/exe/bundle:48:in block in <top (required)>’
from /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.11/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:103:in with_friendly_errors' from /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.11/exe/bundle:36:in <top (required)>’
from /home/circleci/.rubygems/bin/bundle:25:in load' from /home/circleci/.rubygems/bin/bundle:25:in ’

Exited with code exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its issue of circle ci ruby 3. Downgraded and it’s working now.